# Laravel force delete fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Role Model

```
class Role extends EntrustRole
{
  public function permissions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', Config::get('entrust::permission_role_table'));
  }
}
```

Now i would like to delete a certain role

```
$role = Role::where("display_name",'=', $request->route("role"))->first();
$role->delete() //fails
$role->forceDelete() //also fails
```

The above returns an error

> message www/html/laravel/keybrands/vendor/laravel/framework/
>   src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php"
>
> "Class name must be a valid object or a string"

The permission model is in the App namespace.

Where could i be going wrong?

Comment: Show the role modal

Comment: @Vikash role model is in the question

Comment: "*Where could i be going wrong*". Error: "*Class name must be a valid object or a string*". Keyword: **Class name**. Where do you use class names in the code you gave us? In `belongsMany` method. So, there's your debugging 101 (there's also the whole error stack trace that would give you that particular line as well, make use of it).

Comment: probably there is a Role class already, change the class name to something temporary and try it out.

Comment: I see the problem was actually caused by the Entrust trait.By adding the users relationship in the role model now works.

Comment: do `dd($role)` before deleting and see, are you getting the same error ?, if yes then there is a problem in your belongsToMany function. check the config value is it coming or not, then second argument to belongsToMany function it should be the column in role table which is referring the id of permission table

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
class Role extends EntrustRole
{

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, config('entrust::permission_role_table'));
    }
}
```

Comment: after countless debugging ive seen the error is caused by entrust trait. I had to add the users relationship in role model now this works.

Comment: That's good. I wouldn't recommend `Entrust` for use in Laravel 5.1+ apps. `spatie-laravel-permission` & 'JospehSilber/bouncer' are far better ACL plugins for Laravel than Entrust.

Answer (score 0):

Checking on the stacktrace showed the error being caused by the entrust trait.

I have managed top resolve this by adding to the role model.

```
    public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('auth.providers.users.model'),Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'),Config::get('entrust.role_foreign_key'),Config::get('entrust.user_foreign_key'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define User model in `config/auth.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Defining Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'model' => App\User::class,
];
```